Relationship of average root of functions to root of average function
Let $f(x, a) = ( a x - 1 ) / ( \exp( a x ) - 1 )$. Note that $f$ has a root at $x = 1 / a$.
Let $x^\star$ be the root of $f(\cdot, a_1 ) + f( \cdot, a_2)$, where $a_1, a_2 > 0$. By plotting and numerical methods I believe it is the case that $x^\star$ is greater than the average root $( 1/a_1 + 1/a_2 )/2$, but I cannot prove it. I can show that $x^\star$ is greater than $2/(a_1+a_2)$, but I am hoping for an tighter result; Jensen's inequality points in the wrong direction.
Is it the case that, for the function $f$, the root of the average of multiple $f$s exceeds the average root of the same $f$s?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are $a_1$ and $a_2$ positive?

Yes, they are positive. Thank for for the clarification.

I assume that $a$ and $b$ are both positive.
Hoping that you do not mind, I shall change notations $a=a_1$ ane $b=a_2$ and without loss of gnerality $b=k a$ (with $k>1$).
So, the two term function write
$$F(x)=\frac{a x-1}{e^{a x}-1}+\frac{a k x-1}{e^{a k x}-1}$$ and we need to look at what happens around
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2}   \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{k+1}{2 a k}$$
Expanded as a Taylor series built around $x=x_0$,
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\,T_n(k)\,(x-x_0)^n$$
$\forall k >1$, we have
$$T_0(k) <0 \qquad T_1(k)> 0 \qquad T_2(k)< 0\qquad T_3(k)> 0$$
So, by Darboux theorem, $x_0$ is an underestimate of the solution.
For a quick check, let $a=2$ and $b=3$ which gives $x_0=\frac 5 {12}=0.416667$; the first iterate of Newton method is $x_1=0.426663$ and the "exact" solution is $0.427062$.

How do you get the first line, which exchanges $1 / ( exp( ax ) - 1 )$ for $exp( 1 - ax )$? The -1 is unfortunately in the denominator, not in the exponent.

@kyle. I shall check tomorrow. For the Time being, I delete

Thank you, this is exceptionally clear.
